# How to stop Index of/?

Tags: php, html, indexing, web

I have a web server that I do a ton of code testing and projects on. And I go to a page without an index.php (I am aware) and it shows index of/.

How do I stop index of/ from showing up when I don't have an index page?
I would prefer it show an error page, such as "Error | Forbidden" or something along those lines, I see it on a lot of websites but just can't figure out how to do it.
Any help?

Comment: create a index.php / .html file with the error ""Error | Forbidden" on it?

Comment: Good idea. I'll try it out

Comment: might help to let us know what kind of webserver you are running as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache server, add the following line to your **.htaccess** file in the directory:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: I hope you are placing it in proper directory, right?

Answer (score 0):

On Apache server, add a .htaccess file containing this:
    `deny from all`

To the root of the directory you would like to keep people from viewing.